# Sonata SEO Bundle Site MAP

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am using sonata seo bundle and knp paginator bundle.
My Question is When I added new custom static url like :-(www.symfony.in/blog)
in our KNP Menu.It's added successfully. But When I run the :-

```
php app/console sonata:seo:sitemap --scheme=http web www.symfony.in --env=prod
```

Command execute successfully But in sitemap Blog url(www.symfony.in/blog) not added.

Any one know how to add custom url in Sonata SEO Bundle in Sitemap ?

I am google it but nothing found !

Thnaks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a SitemapIterator in order to add your custom URLs to the Sitemap, as described in [the documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/seo/master/doc/reference/sitemap.html). This is an Iterator that you will have to declare as a service, and then reference into the `sonata_seo.sitemap.services` configuration.